# Best data structure to use for playable regions in a game and how to change behaviour at runtime

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, c++14

I am making a Defcon inspired text based nuclear war game where you have to survive with the least casualties and you can upgrade your weapons and form alliances etc. In the game you can play as several regions e.g. Russia, USA, Europe. Each region has access to the same weapons and are exactly the same except that they have different values for the cost, range, number and damage of each of their weapons and need to be able to upgrade these variables as the game progresses.

At run-time the user will select the region that they play and the rest will be played by AI. AI-controlled regions every second have a random chance of upgrading their Weapon variables and the player can upgrade his own if he chooses to.

At the moment my weapon class looks like this:

```
class Weapon 
{
private: // Weapon variables which every continent will have unique values for
    int count;
    int damage;
    float cost;
    int range;

public:
    void upgradeRange(Weapon wep, float p) {
        float percentDecimal = p / 100;
        float modifier = percentDecimal + 1;
        wep.range * modifier;

    // more functions for upgrading each Weapon variable 
    // functions for setting and getting each weapon variable because they are private
    }
};
```

And I have a WeaponArsenal Class where each weapon is defined: (at the moment each region class has its own WeaponArsenal object and therefore can define its own unique Weapon values).

```
class WeaponArsenal
{ /* Weapon Types */
public:
    Weapon icbm; // intercontinental ballistic missile
    Weapon mrbm; // medium range ballistic missile
    Weapon srbm; // short range ballistic missile
    Weapon bomb;

    WeaponArsenal() { 

        // DEFAULT ICBM VALUES
        icbm.setCount(0);
        icbm.setCost(120);
        icbm.setRange(8000);
        icbm.setDamage(80);

        // DEFAULT MRBM VALUES
        mrbm.setCount(0);
        mrbm.setCost(100);
        mrbm.setRange(2000);
        mrbm.setDamage(70);

        // DEFAULT SRBM VALUES
        srbm.setCount(0);
        srbm.setCost(80);
        srbm.setRange(800);
        srbm.setDamage(55);
    }
};
```

I now need to have each region stored in a data structure which allows their unique WeaponArsenal weapon values to be changed as the game develops without affecting the other regions. I want to know which data structure is best for this purpose because I think having a class for each region is very repetitive and not very easy to set at run-time.

I also would like to know how to change the player chosen region's weapon values at run-time without knowing which region he/she will chose. Should I make a pointer to this data structure that points to a different region at the start based on input? How do I allow the non player chosen regions which will be AI operated to call their AI functions? Could I use an EnemyRegion class with all common enemy region methods and if so how will I determine which continents should call these methods at run-time after the player has chosen their region.

I am reasonably new to C++ and have been told that I could use a map for each region from the standard library but I have no knowledge of the standard library and how I could apply maps for my specific uses. I would also still need to know about how the region behaviour can change at runtime.

The full code so far is available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/exitc0d3/fb80a2ff6c4499a5b842b037424676eb/):

Comment: Have  static array of `WeaponArsenal` - as it doesn't grow/shrink dynamically, that should be good enough. Keep either a `std::map<std::string, WeaponArsenal&>` (a dictionary of arsenals indexed by the name/code of each owner) or a `std::map<std::string, size_t>`  (a dictionary of arsenal position in the array of arsenals,  indexed by the name/code of each owner).`WeaponArsenal* playerChoice` will allow a situation in which the player hasn't yet chosen its side. Ah, yes - get to know [the std containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: btw, in you `upgradeRange` you surely wanted to say: `wep.range *= modifier;`

Comment: Thank you @AdrianColomitchi that should be very helpful. I think I will also  add one Region class with some methods and an EnemyRegion class with some other enemy specific methods which I can set regions to at run-time. Also you are right about upgradeRange!

Comment: `Region` - seem like a good idea. `EnemyRegion` - mmmm... not so sure about it. Isn't it better to have `std::vector<Region&> enemies; std::vector<Region&> allies;` as data members of your `Region` class? If later you want to `region.bomb(Region& other)`, you just need to call the `region.hasAsAlly(Region& other)` check before the code triggering the attack. What's so specific about `EnemyRegion`s?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I meant EnemyRegion as a child of Region and all ai controlled regions would count as an EnemyRegion, a better term of course would be AIRegion probably. Thanks for the more information though because that is something I want to implement.

Comment: Oh, come on! No alliances? No neutrals? No [propaganda/secrets/population riots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_War_(card_game))? No [Endgame: Singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endgame:_Singularity) involved, all just a random AI? :)

Comment: To start with everything will be based on random events which the player has to respond to so it will be more political but don't worry there will be alliances and enemies and hopefully as I learn a bit more I can make it better

Comment: @adr why have the array at all, why not store the data in the map?

Comment: @Yakk you store the data in the map, then establish relationships (not `has-a`, but `is-associated-with` type of relations. Similar to the geographic situations: all the regions have their place on the map, but have friends/foes *relations* with the others without *having the others*.

Comment: @adr I do not see how your response has anything to do with my question.

Comment: @Yakk since I seems to misunderstood your question, please rephrase it or be more specific.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi "Have static array of WeaponArsenal" -- why bother with the static array?  That seems like pointless indirection. Simply store the instances of `WeaponArsenal` in a map from RegionName to WeaponArsenal.

Comment: @Yakk Ah, I see. Use the best of the two world in accessing your dta: by position and by name. Actually, I'd do it declaring the Regions as 
BnBDim's answer suggest (straight access as variables), storing their *references* in an array (convenience when accessing by position) and storing their references in a `region-name` indexed map (convenience in accessing by name). Each of them have their own strengths in certain contexts and weaknesses in others.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to have a Region class containing a WeaponArsenal object.

```
class Region
{
public:
    WeaponArsenal arsenal;
}
```

Then you could easily do what you described.

```
Region usa;
usa.arsenal.bomb.upgradeRange();
```

Also you shouldn't have to pass a Weapon object to the upgradeRange function.

Comment: `usa.arsenal.bomb.upgradeRange();` Meh, the money for the upgrade don't come from my pocket then :)